# Bigquery: pivot while adding a total x line

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery, pivot, pivot-table

I've built a dynamic pivot table in BigQuery that does what I need with an exception.

The final goal is to also obtain a sum of each row's items' total in a supplemental column that is not part of the dynamic columns' set passed to the pivot call.

I've tried using window functions and partition without success.

Any idea?

Below a small extract of the data

```
Product,agent,qty
Apple,Jon,10
Banana,Jon,5
Apple,Mark,20
```

Even if I can SUM in the inner query the total quantity for each agent, I couldn't figure out how to expose in the PIVOT IN.
Everything I've tried so far returns just 1, as the single line of items, but not the sun (e.g Jon, 15, and Mark 20)

Any idea?

Comment: Please make use of CTE. Each table in these `WITH` statement can be addressed. Create one CTE table with the `PIVOT`. Use this table to work with the window function.

Comment: So have all the query I have done so far in a CTE then select again all the field and do a group by our so?

Comment: Ok, since some of my columns where dynamic, the solution required a group by in between with dynamic columns regexp_replaced with non-necessary characters or replaced with backtick to make them columns. Couldn't figure out a better way.

Comment: Hi @Andrea Moro, Is your issue resolved as per the above comment ? If not then, could you share the sample query that you are using and any other workarounds that you have already tried ?

Comment: I could actually arrive to obtain the expected results, though I'm not sure whether the query performance are the best. The sample data above are simplified from my real scenario, and recreating a synthetic dataset it will be taking a while. To summarise though, I followed what @samuel said but applied a GROUP BY at the end to have the desired nesting. Is this the best solution, or can you think to anything else?

Comment: Hi @Andrea Moro, I have posted the community answer, if my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Andrea Moro and @samuel in the above comments, you can make use of CTE, each table in these `WITH` statements can be addressed. You can create one CTE table with the `PIVOT` and  use this table to work with the window function.

To get the expected result with the required nesting, a possible solution could be that you can use a `group by`, at the end in between with dynamic columns regexp_replaced with non-necessary characters or replaced with backtick to make them columns.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.